# Apache Airflow benchmark for simple frequently DAGs/tasks?

Tags: airflow, etl, benchmarking, airflow-scheduler

I am considering Apache AIrflow as one of the components in my project.

Can't find an approximate benchmarking. Therefore, I have a number of questions.
Take for example a P with 8 CPUs and 32 Gb RAM.

And DAG with such tasks: **"curl REST" => "extract content" => "save to DB" => "send email"**

- Is Apache AIrflow suitable for frequent tasks that will be executed every second?
- How much parallel task can such PC per second?
- How much memory does such DAG require?
- Will Apache AIrflow do a good job if for example 1000 DUGs are called every 2-3 seconds?

Share your experience. Thank you!

Comment: Airflow is probably overkill for your project. It's good for tasks that require management of dependencies eg: task C runs after tasks A and B. If you're using Airflow to run single tasks without complicated relationships and dependencies I'd suggest using something much simpler like `cron` or a FaaS like AWS Lambda that provides scheduling.

Comment: @n8sty Thanks. 
I understand you.
But I think it will work for me. I understand that this can be overengineering at first glance. And if you look into the future, how to control and manage cron jobs from 100 clients, each of which has 10-20 different triggers every minute?
Can you share your opinion on my question?